# Android App not executing. Activity Class does not exist

Tags: java, android

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.justjava/com.example.justjava.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.justjava/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.justjava/com.example.justjava.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Error while Launching activity [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8xlt.png)

Comment: Please share your manifest file

Comment: Have you declared MainActivity in ManiFest files and make as laucher ?

Answer (score 0):

add your launcher Activity in manifest file.
Activity not added in Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `manifest.xml` must declare one of your activity as launcher using:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

here a sample `MainActivity` as main launcher:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```